# Can't make a view overlay another view in FrameLayout

Tags: android, android-relativelayout, android-view, android-framelayout

I want  to make my ImageView on top of my Button, but the button will always overlay the ImageView , no matter which layout I choose or the way I arrange my layout... this is an example of a FrameLayout that I tried:

EDIT:
just for simplifying my question : Why doesn't the FrameLayout work as it should? (you can copy this code to your Android Studio and see yourself)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:padding="0.1dp">

    <Button
        android:clickable="false"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:text="135"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/buttonText"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/triangle"
        android:id="@+id/triangle"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I solved the problem myself by changing the **Button** to **TextView** . The FrameLayout default behavior isn't working here because Android system always set Buttons to overlay other views (so the user will always be able to click the button).

Answer (score 6):

I experienced the same issue (of note, if the button is disabled it would not overlay all the other views), and found a fix. Simply wrap the button and image in separate sub-frame layouts.

```
<FrameLayout>...
    <FrameLayout>...
        <Button ... />
    </FrameLayout>
    <FrameLayout>...
        <ImageView ... />
    </FrameLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

I don't know if this has any negative repercussions, aside from perhaps a bit of inefficiency, but it seems to work fine.

Comment: Your solution worked for me; however, it's not necessary to wrap both views in FrameLayouts or put them both in a FrameLayout at all, just wrapping the one I want to be in the background did it for me. EDIT: clarification

Answer (score 5):

In the Android 5.0 (API 21) and above, you must add **android:elevation** into the view.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:padding="0.1dp">

    <Button
        android:clickable="false"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:text="135"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/buttonText"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/triangle"
        android:id="@+id/triangle"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
        android:elevation="3dp" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call bringToFront() on the view you want to get in the front

Example:

```
yourView.bringToFront();
```

Comment: bringToFront() doesn't work for me... maybe I'm doing something wrong with my FrameLayout?

Comment: Why are you using frame layout for this? Can't it be done with RelativeLayout?

Comment: I tried RelativeLayout but without successes, so I tried FrameLayout because overlaying views is  the main use of FrameLayouts

Comment: Use RelativeLayout and in java code use view. bringToFront();. I bet it will work.

Comment: Edit your question by adding snippet where you assigned the view and used bringToFront(); . I think you are doing something wrong in java code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85495/discussion-between-aawaz-gyawali-and-james).

Comment: bringToFront() did not work for me either, I posted an answer of a hack that did work