# Views gone after changing app to use AppCompat

Tags: android, android-layout, android-appcompat

Previously, my app did not use AppCompat at all, but now I need it due to a few libraries which require it. The problem is, that after I started using AppCompat, some `Views` (`ImageView` and `SeekBar`) are not showing:

[image]

What has changed is I am now using `AppCompatActivity` from v7 support library (instead of `Activity`) and `Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar` (instead of `android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar`).

The hieararchy of the layout is as follows:

[image: A frame layout contains a relative layout. The relative layout contains two images and another frame layout that has a seek bar. The relative layout is what goes missing.]

I know it is quite complex but this was the only way I was able to achieve what I wanted. (The *foreground* FrameLayout is used so I can dim the rest of the app when a specific popup dialog opens up. Grid is achieved by using multiple LinearLayouts. To get vertical SeekBars I needed to use a FrameLayout with SeekBar inside and then rotate it. The red and blue "tiles" are actually [FButtons](https://github.com/hoang8f/android-flat-button))

How do I fix this? Is the reason I am not seeing the ImageButtons and SeekBar because of too many nested views?

Comment: Could you add (or link to) your entire layout xml? I'd like to be able to try to duplicate the problem in my own IDE.

Comment: Sure: [activity_main.xml](https://expirebox.com/download/8b61e0a0b24ab1cd6a72f8f04e421d4d.html)

Comment: @PrimožKralj In the future, please edit your question to include the relevant parts of the layout instead of providing a download link to it in a comment. Took a look at your XML and the `ImageViews` have their `visibility` set to `gone`. Do you change them from code?

Comment: Yes, the visibility of `ImageView`s is controlled programaticaly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can reproduce the issue and this is so weird.
However I managed to show `ImageViews` and `SeekBar` by adding `android:elevation="2dp"`into the ImageView's `RelativeLayout`. I know this is not a solution, besides this attribute is for Android API >= 21.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:elevation="2dp">
        // ImageViews and SeekBar here
        ...
</RelativeLayout>
```

---

Another workaround but works prior and above API 21.
Tested on emulator API 18.

Put this in your **`value/styles.xml`**:

```
<style name="my_style">
    // let this empty
</style>
```

Put this in your **`value-v21/styles.xml`**:

```
<style name="my_style">
    <item name="android:elevation">5dp</item> // above 2dp apparently...
</style>
```

And add `style="@style/my_style"`to **each** `RelativeLayout` I was talking about in first answer.

```
<RelativeLayout
    style="@style/my_style"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
        // ImageViews and SeekBar here
        ...
</RelativeLayout>
```

While digging a little more, I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31891202/cant-make-a-view-overlay-another-view-in-framelayout).

Comment: Well, this is encouraging, thanks. I would still need a solution for API < 21 though.

Comment: I appreciate your effort but it's still not perfect. When the `FButton` is in a pressed state the `RelativeLayout` (containing ImageViews and SeekBar) dissapears (and reappears as soon as it's not pressed anymore).

Comment: @PrimožKralj I think that Punchlag is on the track to solving your issue. It definitely looks like an elevation problem. For instance, in the emulator, if I display with API 20 or below, I see your vanished items. With API 21+, I don't. Setting elevation on the RelativeLayout solves it. You may have an additional issue with button animation. Take a look at [this posting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27080338/android-5-0-androidelevation-works-for-view-but-not-button) to see if this is related to your problem.

Comment: @PrimožKralj  You do also seem to be running into a feature implemented in API 21: [StateListAnimator](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/StateListAnimator.html). Either set `android:stateListAnimator="@null"` or set elevation high enough to overcome whatever `StateListAnimator` is doing. (6dp seems high enough).

Comment: Solved. The elevation I had was 5dp, that's why it wasn't working. After setting it to 6dp, it works. Also, as @Cheticamp wrote, adding `android:stateListAnimator="@null"` to `FButton` works too. Thanks guys